# Upload file to a general website application

Tags: java, c++, http, upload, httpwebrequest

I want to upload a file to a general website.

It seems I'll have to use HTTP requests which I can obtain through http://www.fiddler2.com/.

But I'm a complete beginner in handling HTTP or webrequests. Could someone guide me into a good tutorial on HTTP requests using C++ or Java?

Most websites are in need of a login for example. Also, does a general website accept those http request to upload a file? For uploading a file to a general website it seems you will need a login handler, get the correct request to upload the file and then upload it. To get those correct requests, do I have to see what that specific site asks?

The goal is to upload a file to a general website of choice and expand from there on to more websites.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java

Comment: check out [this][1] link


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615441/upload-file-from-java-client-using-http-post-to-java-server

It shows the same thing which you asked.

Comment: Most websites are in need of a login for example. I can't see these codes handling this. Also, does a general website accept those http request to upload a file? 
For uploading a file to a general website it seems you will need a login handler, get the correct request to upload the file and then upload it. 
To get those correct requests, do I have to see what that specific site asks?